# MPMoviePlayerController MovieAccessLogEvent - Inflated observedBitrate

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, bitrate, adaptive-bitrate

I am currently working with the `MPMoviePlayerController` and am analysing metrics for video playback. Specifically, analysing adaptive bitrates.

As part of testing I load a particular rendition of the video at a fixed bitrate (`995kbps`), however when reading from the `observedBitrate` property of my `MPMovieAccessLogEvent`, this value is much more inflated - to the tune of around `15mbps`.

Is there any known reason why this bitrate being returned is considerably higher than that of the playback? I have double checked all values, and all playback, and it is definitely the `observedBitrate` that is inflated.

According to the documentation, this value is:

> The empirical throughput across all media downloaded for the movie
> player, in bits per second.

**Update**

I posted this question on the developer forums and have received an answer, which is still just conjecture but thought it might aid the question anyway and maybe provoke a better answer.

> https://devforums.apple.com/thread/216659?tstart=0
>
> It would be worth checking your HLS video with mediastreamvalidator
> which will download and measure your segment bit rates.

Comment: +1 Interesting question - I never really doublechecked those logged values. Assuming that you wont get a proper answer here (likely), go ahead and file a TSI.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it is strange, I was thinking maybe 'throughput across all media' means that there is also additional overhead being included with this bitrate of total download. But can't seem to deduce any pattern when I play my other renditions (240kbps, 640kbps).

Comment: I do certainly see that the actual downloaded data is more than the played stream bitrate as there is at least the point of up- and down-scaling the chosen stream bitrate while playing. In other words, the player may sometimes throw away chunks in the favor of a different bandwidth while streaming. That however should never add up to a factor of 2 or higher and it would only apply to http-streaming.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple answer to this - the `indicatedBitrate` of a `MPMovieAccessLogEvent` (or `AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent` for `AVPlayer`) is the bitrate from the current playlist, so is an average bitrate required to play the stream.

However, the `observedBitrate` is NOT averaged - it is the instantaneous bitrate (or download speed) which the player achieved while downloading a particular chunk of video.

Example: Playing a playlist with a 1000 Kb/s stream, in chunks of 10 seconds each. The device can achieve over 10MB/s download over WiFi, so it takes less than 1 second to download each chunk. Therefore, the player is downloading at over 10,000 Kb/s during each chunk.
I'd expect the player to return (approximately) these values:

`indicatedBitrate`: 1000 Kb/s

`observedBitrate`: 10,000 Kb/s

I'd been mystified by these large values myself, but I think this explains it.

This is just for illustration - these values are not very meaningful since we don't really know how long it takes to download a chunk, or indeed how big each chunk is. All the `observedBitrate` really tells you is how well the player is managing to keep up with the bitrate needed to play the stream. If the former is 10x bigger than the latter, then it is only using 10% of the available time to download each chunk. This ratio may be used as a quality-of-service indicator.
For example, if the `observedBitrate` is less than the `indicatedBitrate` then it is very likely that the player will stall due to buffering, but as long as it is greater, then all is well and the stream is likely to play smoothly.

Comment: ,your explanation about observedbitrate is good , I request you to explain average observed bitrate calculation with an example.It will help to understand it better .Thanks in advance.

Comment: karthik - I've added an extra paragraph to expand on this aspect. Thank you for pointing it out - I saw that my example could be misunderstood so hopefully it is now clearer.

Comment: thanks for the clarfication and I have posted a question regarding playlist current bit rate , can you please help me here .http://stackoverflow.com/q/32406838/1730345