# Get the player bitrate mean value, during a session.

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer, http-live-streaming

According to http://blog.spooningfork.com/post/44787139787/http-live-streaming-ios-avplayer, the observedBitrate is the bitrate that the player is seeing. 
However is it an instant value or a mean value ?

the doc says : *"The empirical throughput across all media downloaded, in bits per second."*

I don't really get this explanation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation would indicate it is the average.

I take the meaning of *throughput across all media downloaded* to mean it is averaging the value. If it was the instantaneous bitrate they probably would have named the property `currentBitrate`.

However, to me it doesn't make much sense to provide the standard derivation of a bitrate for a segment, but not the average bitrate for the segment, so the `observedBitrate` could be the average bitrate for the segment and the documentation could be wrong.

Comparing the value `numberOfBytesTransferred / transferDuration` to the `observedBitrate` might help you on getting to the bottom of your question.

Comment: I find observedBitRate is very when compare to the indicateBitRate , I find this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31947178/1730345 says the obervedBitRate is the rate at which the segment is downloaded(not played) , do you have an idea how to find the bit rate experienced by avplayer for playing the stream ?